# Display password protected posts to logged in users

Tags: posts, multisite, buddypress, password, publish

In a WPMU & BuddyPress installation, I want to directly **show the password protected posts to logged in users** without asking them for posts passwords... and still be accessible to guests (non-members) by entering the posts protected passwords!

Real-World Use Case.
I need this for one of my blog/site: **apply-for-membership**.mysite.com

1. Any visitor (guests/non-members) can apply for a membership by entering they Application (Guests will have a form so they can add new post with visibility: password protected)
2. MySite Members can view all the Guests Applications (without entering the passwords) and comment on them, making ratings, investigate, adding questions, etc.
3. Guests come back to site - enter they post password - and comment on they application, answering the questions of MySite members.

PS: *The all idea is to keep applications only visible to site members and certainly for each applicant, by entering they own password.*

**Any other solution will do** : plugin, function...

Comment: Please go back to your old questions and care about them. Follow the answers and comments and find a solution. That's part of the deal/the system.

Answer (score 2):

Simply search your templates for [`post_password_required()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_password_required) and wrap it into [`if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in).

Comment: Could you hook post_password_required() as well to save time if the OP has multiple themes?

Comment: @BandonRandon Good Q. Haven't ever heard of such a hook. Maybe you want to add another answer?

Comment: I haven't heard of such a hook either was more wondering if you had. If I find anything I'll post :).

Comment: This is my single.php: http://pastebin.com/nSDAjdfZ. My theme templates has no "post_password_required"... can you please give me a more explicit example, thanks

Comment: Why didn't you say that this is a buddypress site? I've got no idea about this.

Comment: I think "password protected posts" has nothing to do with BuddyPress. Just give me an example of how to implement this script on the default twentyeleven single.php template... http://pastebin.com/zUJbyHqe